# Setting up Master page with a template in MVC-4 using aspx engine

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Since, I'm new in MVC, I've a question on how to set up a master page in MVC-4 using a template that I already have in aspx engine (not razor). After a ton of research, somehow I could able to run a sample index page using the master page which is placed inside shared folder.

But the problem is that the CSS files and .js files for the master page are not being triggered. So, what I see after running page is not as it expected to be.

I tried putting the js and CSS files inside content folder and tried putting in shared folder as well, but still the style is not showing up.

Master page code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- js -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- //js -->
        <!-- for-mobile-apps -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Princi_Gym Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
        Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design">
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false);
                function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <!-- //for-mobile-apps -->
        <!-- hover-effects -->

        <!-- //hover-effects -->
        <!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
<!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
<!--start-top-nav-script-->

<!--End-top-nav-script-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <body style="">
<!-- header -->
    <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-top-left" id="home">
            <ul>
                <li class="activ"><a href="#">LAST NOTICE</a></li>
                <li>Aliquam sit amet gravida ipsum,vitae scelerisque mi.Maecenas ullamcorper in 
                    metus a ullamcorper.Sed dictum neque </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="header-top-right">
            <p>Phone Number:<span> 043-234-3453</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        <div class="head-logo">
            <a href="index.html"><span> </span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-top">

        <div class="navigation">
                 <span class="menu"></span> 
                    <ul class="navig">
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="act">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="plan active"><a href="single.html">CLASSES</a>
                            <ul class="sub-nav sub">
                                <li><a href="single.html">DROP ITEM1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="single.html">DROP ITEM2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="404.html">PAGES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="trainers.html">TRAINERS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="home-box">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="search">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type and search..." required=" ">
                </form>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
            <!-- script-for-menu -->
         <script>
             $("span.menu").click(function () {
                 $(" ul.navig").slideToggle("slow", function () {
                 });
             });
         </script>
         <!-- script-for-menu -->

<!-- //header -->
<!-- banner -->

<!-- //banner -->
<!-- banner-bottom -->
    <div class="banner-bottom">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FeaturedContent" runat="server" />
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptsSection" runat="server" />
    </div>  


<!-- //banner-bottom -->
<!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer-icon footer-icon-top">
            <a href="#home" class="scroll"><img src="images/row.png" alt=" "></a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-social">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="dribble"> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="facebook"> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="twitter"> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="be"> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="in"> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fli"> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="rad"> </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="foot">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="single.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="trainers.html">ARCHIVES</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <p>Template by <a href="http://w3layouts.com/">w3layouts</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- //footer -->
<!-- here stars scrolling icon -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /*
            var defaults = {
                containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
                containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
                scrollSpeed: 1200,
                easingType: 'linear' 
            };
            */

            $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

        });
    </script>
<!-- //here ends scrolling icon -->

<a href="#" id="toTop" style="display: none;"><span id="toTopHover"></span>To Top</a></body>
        <div id="body">

    </body>
</html>
```

And the sample page code is as follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page - My ASP.NET MVC Application
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexFeatured" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>Home Page.</h1>
                <h2><%: ViewBag.Message %></h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
                The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET MVC.
                If you have any questions about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx/1?MVC" title="ASP.NET MVC Forum">our forums</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
    <ol class="round">
        <li class="one">
            <h5>Getting Started</h5>
            ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
            enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you full control over markup
            for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET MVC includes many features that enable
            fast, TDD-friendly development for creating sophisticated applications that use
            the latest web standards.
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245151">Learn more…</a>
        </li>

        <li class="two">
            <h5>Add NuGet packages and jump-start your coding</h5>
            NuGet makes it easy to install and update free libraries and tools.
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245153">Learn more…</a>
        </li>

        <li class="three">
            <h5>Find Web Hosting</h5>
            You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features
            and price for your applications.
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245157">Learn more…</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</asp:Content>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Can you access the css/js files directly via their url? If not, I would investigate your route config file

Comment: Yes, If I run directly outside the MVC workspace it works perfectly. But its not working when I try to run in MVC